# How do I build a snap in an isolated environment?

Tags: packaging, snap, pbuilder

While building Debian packages, [pbuilder](http://pbuilder.alioth.debian.org/) (and similar tools) help in building packages in an isolated environment, so that odd settings in my system don't cause problems in building:

> pbuilder aims to be an easy-to-setup system for auto-building Debian
>   packages inside a clean-room environment, so that it is possible to
>   verify that a package can be built on most Debian installations. The
>   clean-room environment is achieved through the use of a base chroot
>   image, so that only minimal packages will be installed inside the
>   chroot.

Is there an equivalent for snapcraft?

---

Context: I just had some locale problems interfere with building [a snap for Cassandra](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/compare/trunk...evandandrea:snap). I'd been getting locale errors that I am too lazy to look into, and during the build process, `javadoc` failed because of Unicode characters in some files. Using `C.UTF-8` as the locale fixed that:

```
export LC_ALL=C.UTF-8
snapcraft
```

However, my locale shouldn't affect building packages, snappy or Debian. Something like pbuilder would be useful here.

Comment: There is a pre-built Cassandra snap package named *cassandra*. To install and configure the cassandra snap package follow the instructions in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1003195/how-can-etc-apt-sources-list-d-object-be-removed/1003200#1003200).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You certainly can. `snapcraft` has a "`cleanbuild`" option which can either (default) build locally inside an lxd container, or remotely (via the `--remote` option).

So:-

Build in a local lxd (needs the `lxd` package to be installed, and [networking setup for LXD](https://insights.ubuntu.com/2016/04/07/lxd-networking-lxdbr0-explained/)):

```
snapcraft cleanbuild
```

Build in a remote lxd:

```
snapcraft cleanbuild --remote remotemachine
```

I followed [this guide](https://stgraber.org/2016/04/12/lxd-2-0-remote-hosts-and-container-migration-612/) to setup remote building on my home server. Works well!

Comment: This doesn't seem to be quite on par with pbuilder - for one thing, it seems to do no caching at all for packages, so each run downloads every package it needs afresh (and worse, from archive.ubuntu.com). And I'm still fighting to make it work for with Java. :/ Those are different questions, though.