# How can /etc/apt/sources.list.d object be removed?

Tags: apt, software-sources, cassandra

I have added

```
echo "deb http://www.apache.org/dist/cassandra/debian 311x main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cassandra.sources.list
```

Now I want to remove it and install Cassandra in another way.How to delete it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Open `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/cassandra.sources.list` for editing in nano text editor and comment out the line that you want to disable by preceding it with a `#` character at the beginning of the line.

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cassandra.sources.list
```

Change this line:

```
deb http://www.apache.org/dist/cassandra/debian 311x main
```

So that it looks like this:

```
# deb http://www.apache.org/dist/cassandra/debian 311x main
```

<sub>**Nano editor keyboard shortcuts**</sub>
<sub>Use the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> and after that press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to save the file to its current location.</sub>
<sub>Use the keyboard combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> to exit nano.</sub>

Update the list of available software:

```
sudo apt update
```

Comment: I have installed with snap, but now I got cassandra -v
cassandra: command not found
Why?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is `sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cassandra.sources.list` .. this will remove all entries that's in the casandra.sources.list file, but it should only be the one you added.